# How to add javascript function to a QML property?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have written C++ class for "DeviceDiscovery" Type

```
class DeviceDiscovery : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
   //HERE I NEED TO ADD A PROPERTY "deviceFilter" so that below client code can execute, I am not sure which property variable I need to add here.
};
```

*Then registering it via       qmlRegisterType("com.company.Devices" , 1, 0, "DeviceDiscovery");*

In QML, I need to call  deviceFilter property as a callback like  **discovery.deviceFilter()**, so that javascript console log is called.

```
 DeviceDiscovery {
        id: discovery
        deviceFilter: function() { console.log("device filter is called")};
 }

//I need to call
MouseArea{
  anchors.fill:parent
  onClicked:discovery.deviceFilter(); //So that above javascript function gets called.
}
```

Can someone help me, how to add a C++ PROPERTY, which should take javascript function as argument to execute.?

Comment: Q_PROPERTY(QJSValue deviceFilter READ  deviceFilter WRITE setDeviceFilter NOTIFY deviceFilterChanged )    //resolved my issue, now deviceFilter would hold javascript function, I can call it directly from qml with or without parameter.

Comment: QJSValue resolved my issue.

Comment: then publish an answer

Answer (score 1):

**Complete example**

> devicediscovery.h

```
#ifndef DEVICEDISCOVERY_H
#define DEVICEDISCOVERY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QJSValue>

class DeviceDiscovery : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QJSValue deviceFilter READ  deviceFilter WRITE setDeviceFilter)

    QJSValue m_deviceFilter;

public:
    explicit DeviceDiscovery(QObject *parent = nullptr){}
    //GET METHOS
    QJSValue deviceFilter() const
    {
        return m_deviceFilter;
    }

public slots://SET METHOD
    void setDeviceFilter(QJSValue deviceFilter)//This funciton required to set javascript funciton at construction or run time in QML
    {
        m_deviceFilter = deviceFilter;
    }


};

#endif // DEVICEDISCOVERY_H
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "devicediscovery.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<DeviceDiscovery>("com.company.Devices" , 1, 0, "DeviceDiscovery");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

> main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import com.company.Devices 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    DeviceDiscovery {
           id: discovery
           //default javascript
           deviceFilter: function(numberCount) { console.log("function called with argument")
           console.log(numberCount)};
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        discovery.deviceFilter(5)//call with parameter
        //Runtime assignment of new javascript callback.
        discovery.deviceFilter = function() { return console.log("function called with out argument") }
        discovery.deviceFilter()//call without parameter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a signal *deviceFilterChanged* that is emitted on callback in your C++ logic. This signal can be listened for in your QML custom type *DeviceDiscovery* so you can write your logs and QML action in here.

```
DeviceDiscovery {
        id: discovery
        onDeviceFilterChanged: {
            console.log("device filter is called")};
        }
}
```

Here you can read about how to expose signals to QML: [Exposing Signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-signals)

Comment: This is not the answer, I am looking for. My original question is to hold javascript function as a property, this is for callback and runtime javascript assignment. I found answer commented on questin itself.